# Align sprite image nav buttons in header in CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to create a nav menu with sprite images, I'm almost there but I'm having trouble getting them to align within the header. Can someone tell me what I'm missing? If you click on the Activity Feed button you will see how I want it to align, to the right of the red border of the logo container: http://timc-projects.com/VR%20BLOG/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Replace this css with your css hopefully help you.

```
        <style>
    #logoContainer {
        border-right: 1px solid #9e0b0f;
        float: left;
        height: 70px;
        margin-top: 12px;
        width: 325px;
    }
    ul#nav-top {
        float: left;
        height: 70px;
        list-style: outside none none;
        margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
        width: 333px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Thank you Ashish, that was a big help. Now the nav buttons don't align to the red border. I can set a negative margin but I don't think that would be a good solution.

Comment: Replace this             <style>
                    ul#nav-top {
   float: left;
   height: 70px;
   list-style: outside none none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 333px;
           }
                   </style>

Comment: Very good, thank you. I thought I checked that but I guess I need to get some sleep!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this CSS for perfect layout.

```
#logoContainer {
border-right: 1px solid #9e0b0f;
float: left;
height: 59px;
margin-top: 12px;
width: 325px;
}
ul#nav-top {
float: left;
height: 70px;
list-style: outside none none;
margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
width: 333px;
}

.logo {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("images/sprite-nav.png") repeat scroll 0 0;
height: 105px;
margin-left: 36px;
margin-top: -4px;
position: relative;
top: 11px;
width: 270px;
}

 #logoContainer {
border-right: 1px solid #9e0b0f;
float: left;
height: 60px;
margin-top: 12px;
width: 325px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Makwana, that worked great but the nav buttons still don't align flush with the red border. I can set a negative margin but that does't seem like a good practice.